# The feature names should match those that were passed during fit

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

Im trying to calculate the r squared value after the creation of a model using sklearn linear regression.

Im simply

1. importing a csv dataset
2. filtering the interesting columns
3. splitting the dataset in train and test
4. creating the model
5. making a prediction on the test
6. calculating the r squared in order to see how good is the model to fit the test dataset

the dataset is taken from https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/jeremylarcher/american-house-prices-and-demographics-of-top-cities

the code is as following

```
''' Lets verify if there s a correlation between price and beds number of bathroom'''

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.read_csv('data/American_Housing_Data_20231209.csv')

df_interesting_columns = df[['Beds', 'Baths', 'Price']]

independent_variables = df_interesting_columns[['Beds', 'Baths']]
dependent_variable = df_interesting_columns[['Price']]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(independent_variables, dependent_variable, test_size=0.2)

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

prediction = model.predict(X_test)

print(model.score(y_test, prediction))
```

but i get the error

ValueError: The feature names should match those that were passed during fit.
Feature names unseen at fit time:

- Price
  Feature names seen at fit time, yet now missing:
- Baths
- Beds

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last line is wrong. You misunderstood the [`score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.score) method. `score` take `X` and `y` as parameter not the `y_true` and `y_pred`

Try:

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

print(r2_score(y_test, prediction))
# 0.24499127100887863
```

Or with the `score` method:

```
print(model.score(X_test, y_test))
# 0.24499127100887863
```